# Confusion about return value from link list while recursion

Tags: c

I have a snippet to reverse the link list recursively

```
struct node *Reverse_List(struct node *p)
{
        if (p->next == NULL) {
                head = p;
                return;
        }

        p = Reverse_List(p->next); ----> why this is wrong to get the value into pointer p ?

        struct node *ptr1 = p->next;
        p->next = ptr1->next;           
        ptr1->next = p;
}
```

This code works well with "Reverse_List(p->next);" but if I take the return value of it in pointer p (as pointed in the snippet), its gives me Segmentation fault.

Comment: If your program crashes then first of all make sure you have the smallest possible input sample to replicate the crash (it will make it easier to debug). Then use a debugger to catch the crash as it happens, to see when and where it happens, and examine the values of all involved variables at that point. If that doesn't help, then you need to use the debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values, to see when things starts to go wrong. Don't forget to step into the recursive calls.

Comment: To help with debugging when stepping through the code, I recommend you draw every operation on the list using pencil and paper. Draw nodes as squares and links/pointers as arrows. Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify them. This visualization might make it easier to see the problem.

Comment: Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Milan It is a bad idea to define the function such a way that it depends ion the global variable head.

Comment: Have you ever used 2 mirrors and faced them to each other? That's what you are trying to do with your `p = Reverse_List(p->next);`.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the code defines a function expected to return a pointer.

```
struct node *Reverse_List(struct node *p)
```

And you need the return value to do the recursive calling.

```
p = Reverse_List(p->next); ----> why this is wrong to get the value into pointer p ?
```

But nowhere you have returned anything in the function body.